# Display paragraphs field as a table?

Tags: paragraphs

Is there a way to display the output of a multiple value paragraphs field in a node as a table? The paragraphs has three fields in it, and I would like to display with labels in the header row, and content rows containing the data for each row in the paragraph.

Comment: Please do not re-post your question, improve the first one instead [How do I display paragraph fields as a table?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/310990/how-do-i-display-paragraph-fields-as-a-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can template paragraph types. In the template, you build the values into whatever output fits your needs. Create a new template type, and loop through the values to create the table.

How to theme paragraphs: https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/paragraphs/theming-paragraphs-in-drupal-8

Comment: Thanks for the help, Jaypan. I added a custom paragraph template, and also had to add some field templates for the node field including the paragraphs. A fair amount of work, that I will need to replicate for the other two paragraph types I'm using. It would be so much easier if there was a preconfigured way to output multiple item paragraphs as a table! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.